# How the program interprets values in variables

Tags: c

I've got a quick question.
If I had a variable like `int x = 30;`

I understand that the value 30 is changed into a 4-byte integer, and then it checks if the value 30 is stored into the integer variable; if it is, then it works.

If I had `int x = 3.08;` (it should pop out an error), but 3.08 is changed into an 8-byte float, then it checks if the value is stored in a `float`, but it wants to be stored in `int` so it pops out an error.

My main question is: is the value first interpreted into byte (bit format) before placing it into the variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've got a quick question. If I had variable like int x = 30;
>
> I understand that the value 30 is changed into 4 byte integer, then it checkes if the value 30 is stored into integer variable if it is then it works.

By “stored into integer variable,” I think you mean the compiler looks at the type for `x` (which is an `int`) and the type for the initializer `30` (which is an `int` constant) and checks whether they satisfy the rules about what types can be used to initialize what types.

That is correct; the compiler does analyze the types involved. However, given that the initializer is an `int`, it is not merely checking that the object being initialized is an `int`. The C standard says any arithmetic type may be used to initialize any arithmetic type. You can even use a complex number to initialize an `int`, as in `int i = 3.0 + 4.0 * I;`.

> If I had int x = 3.08 (it should pop out an error), but 3.08 is changed into 8 byte float, then it checks if the value is stored in float but it wants to be stored in int so it pops out an error.

While the C standard allows any arithmetic type to be used to initialize any arithmetic type, it also allows compilers to give you warnings about code that is likely to contain a mistake even though that code is allowed by the standard and its behavior is fully defined by the C standard. That is the case here; `int x = 3.08;` does not violate constraints in the C standard, and the C standard does not require any diagnostic message or error for this, but the compiler writers chose to warn you because code that initializes an `int` with a `double` constant may be a mistake rather than a deliberate choice.

Usually such diagnostic messages can be turned on or off via some switch given to the compiler. Also, when the compiler does issue such a message, there is generally a way to work around that. For example, by writing `int x = (int) 3.08;`, we can tell the compiler we are deliberately converting the `double` to an `int`, and then it will not produce that diagnostic message.

> My main question is : is the value first interpreted into byte (bit format) before placing it into the variable ?

There is no required order for how a compiler performs this aspect of its work. It must analyze the code, it must produce diagnostic messages if required by the C standard or chosen by its designers, it must convert constants in source code to bytes that represent them (or otherwise make provision for this), and it must arrange for those bytes to be stored in the object for its initialization. It can do these things in various orders. (Note that these actions can be further changed by optimization, which is beyond the scope of this answer.)

Additionally, the design of compilers is considerably more conceptual than how you are thinking about it currently. There is an entire system for type analysis, and it is both separate from and interleaved with other aspects of the compiler, such as converting constants to bytes that represent them. From my general knowledge of compiler design, I think it is most likely the lexical analyzer of the compiler will read `3.08`, convert it to some representation of the appropriate value, and create an internal “token” for the compiler indicating there is a `double` constant at this point in the source code. Then higher level code analyzes what the consequences of having a `double` at this point are.

However, it is entirely possible to design the compiler so the lexical analyzer reads `3.08`, creates a token indicating there is a `double` constant there, and stores the source text “3.08” with that token, and that the compiler only converts that “3.08” to a floating-point representation after doing further analysis of the source code, including checking the type rules.

So a compiler could do the conversion to bytes and the type checking in either order.

Comment: Thank you very much !!

The most important thing is that first it considers the constant which is 3.08. 
If it was like int x = 'd'; it would consider first the char character change it into byte or just store as a text as " 'd' ",and then analizes the variable. I think of a char as a constant as well so the possibility would be the same like you've shown with 3.08